# Перебор всех вариантов

Tags: алгоритм

помогите пожалуйста решить задачу:

Мне нужно создать алгоритм, который будет находить подходящее расписания для школы ( у нас есть определенное количество классов с разными уроками, которые нужно провести за 6 дней обучения, для каждого урока есть свой учитель, свои ограничения (например, большинство уроков нужно размещать не больше раза в день, некоторые уроки нужно проводить в субботу и т.д.).

Я не прошу решить за меня, просто может подскажете, какой принцип можно для этого использовать, что почитать и т.д.

З.Ы. Был вот такой вот алгоритм, но чем дальше пишу программу, тем больше минусов в нём нахожу

```
private void generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
```

`bool tooMuchLessons = false; string tooMuchLessonsFormName = "";
        bool tooMuchLessonsToTeach = false; string tooMuchLessonsToTeachName = ""; // переменные, содержащие информацию о превышении лимита уроков для учителя/класса в неделю

        r.Next();

        List<L> startLesson = new List<L>(); // список, в котором хранятся данные о первом уроке для перебора
        List<int> startLessonF = new List<int>(); // список, в котором хранятся данные о первок уроке для перебора ( он не изменяется в будущем )
        int[] backs = new int[forms.Count];

        foreach(Form form in forms)
        {
            int k = 0;
            foreach (Lesson lesson in form.lessons) k += lesson.amount;
            if(k > Form.MaxLessonsAmount) { tooMuchLessons = true; tooMuchLessonsFormName = form.number.ToString() + " \"" + form.letter.ToString() + "\""; }
            // проверили превышение лимита уроков для класса в неделю
            L temp = new L(r.Next(0, form.lessons.Count - 1), form.lessons.Count - 1);
            startLesson.Add(temp);
            startLessonF.Add(temp.GetValue());
            // для каждого класса задан случайный первый урок и это значение сохранено
        }

        foreach (Teacher teacher in teachers)
        {
            int k = 0;
            foreach (Form form in forms) foreach (Lesson lesson in form.lessons) if (lesson.teach.fullname == teacher.fullname) k += lesson.amount;
            if (k > Teacher.MaxLessonsAmount) { tooMuchLessonsToTeach = true; tooMuchLessonsToTeachName = teacher.fullname; }
        } // проверяет превышение лимита уроков для учителя в неделю

        if(!tooMuchLessons && !tooMuchLessonsToTeach) // если не превышен лимит уроков для класса/учителя, то начинается перебор расписаний
        {
            schedules = new List<Schedule>(); // Расписания полностью обнуляются
            tschedules = new List<tSchedule>(); // Учительские расписания полностью обнуляются

            foreach (Form form in forms) schedules.Add(new Schedule()); // Создаются расписания, соотвествующие каждому классу
            foreach (Teacher teacher in teachers) tschedules.Add(new tSchedule()); // Создаются расписания, соответствующие каждому учителю

            for (int f_id = 0; f_id < tschedules.Count; f_id++)
            {
                for (int d_id = 0; d_id < 6; d_id++)
                {
                    for (int l_id = 0; l_id < 12; l_id++)
                    {
                        tschedules[f_id].days[d_id].lessons[l_id] = new tLesson("", "");
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int form = 0; form < forms.Count; form++) // Перебираем каждый отдельный класс
            {
                Lesson[] LSN = new Lesson[forms[form].lessons.Count];
                forms[form].lessons.CopyTo(LSN);

                Lesson T;

                for (int i = 0; i < LSN.Count(); i++)
                    for (int k = 0; k < LSN.Count(); k++)
                        if (LSN[i].sub.toughness > LSN[k].sub.toughness)
                        {
                            T = LSN[i];
                            LSN[i] = LSN[k];
                            LSN[k] = T;
                        }

                List<int> LessonsLeft; // Переменная, отвечающаяя за количество оставшихся на неделю определенных уроков
                int LessonsAtAll = -1; // Переменная, отвечающая за количество оставшихся на неделю ВСЕХ уроков

                L LESSON; // Мы создаем переменную для перебора возможных уроков
                L startLessonT = new L(startLesson[form].GetValue(), LSN.Count() - 1); // Создаем переменную, которая будет меняться в случае неудачных расписаний

                int shift = 0; // По стандарту задаем смещение на 0
                int s = 0; int f = 0;

                if (forms[form].secondShift) shift = 6; // Если у класса вторая смена, то смещение на 6

                if (shift == 0)
                {
                    s = 0; f = 6;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = 5; f = 11;
                }

                for (int day = 0; day < 6; day++) // Перебираем каждый день для чистки учительского расписания (удаляем только те уроки, которые ведут у этого класса)
                    for (int lesson = 0; lesson < 12; lesson++) // Перебираем уроки
                        for (int tsched = 0; tsched < tschedules.Count; tsched++) // Проверяем расписание каждого учителя
                            if (tschedules[tsched].days[day].lessons[lesson].form != "" && tschedules[tsched].days[day].lessons[lesson].form == (forms[form].number.ToString() + forms[form].letter)) // Условия обнуления
                                tschedules[tsched].days[day].lessons[lesson] = new tLesson("", ""); // Само обнуление

                bool formFailed = false; // Переменная = true, если расписание сгенерировать не удалось
                int backSave = -1;

                for (int weekImplementations = 0; weekImplementations < LSN.Count() && LessonsAtAll != 0; weekImplementations++) // Если сгенерировать расписание не удалось, то повторяем, пока не закончатся варианты
                {
                    LessonsLeft = new List<int>(); // Обнуляем для правильного подсчета
                    LessonsAtAll = 0; // Обнуляем для правильного подсчета

                    LESSON = new L(startLessonT.GetValue(), LSN.Count() - 1); // Мы создаем переменную для перебора возможных уроков

                    foreach (Lesson lesson in LSN)
                    {
                        LessonsLeft.Add(lesson.amount); // Вводим значения количества определенных уроков на неделю
                        LessonsAtAll += lesson.amount; // Вводим значения количество ВСЕХ уроков на неделю
                    }

                    //MessageBox.Show(LessonsAtAll.ToString());

                    foreach(int day in days) // Перебираем каждый отдельный день
                    {
                        List<int> LessonsADayLeft = new List<int>(); // Переменная, отвечающая за количество оставшихся на день определенных уроков
                        foreach (Lesson lesson in LSN) LessonsADayLeft.Add(lesson.aday); // Вводим значения количества определенных уроков на день

                        for (int lesson = 0; lesson < 12; lesson++)
                            schedules[form].days[day].lessons[lesson] = new Lesson(0, 0, new Subject("", 0), new Teacher(" ", " ", " ", null), false, false); // Предварительно заполняем классное расписание пустыми уроками

                        for (int lesson = s; lesson <= f; lesson++) // Перебираем каждый отдельный урок (первый равен смещению, последний равен 6 + смещение (чтобы уроки размещались на нужной смене)
                        {
                            bool DoubleCheck = false;

                            foreach (Lesson l1 in schedules[form].days[day].lessons)
                                foreach (Lesson l2 in schedules[form].days[day].lessons)
                                    if (l1 == l2) DoubleCheck = true;

                            bool passedSaturdayCheck = (LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].saturday == (day == 5)); // Субботняя проверка
                            bool passedAdditionalCheck = (LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].additional == ((lesson == 6 && shift == 0) || (lesson == 5 && shift == 6)));
                            //MessageBox.Show(passedAdditionalCheck.ToString());
                            bool teacherUnavailable = (tschedules[teachers.IndexOf(LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].teach)].days[day].lessons[lesson].form != ""); // Проверяем, свободен ли учитель
                            int implementations = LSN.Count(); // Количество попыток на установление урока
                            bool passedDoubleCheck = (DoubleCheck && LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].aday == 2 && LessonsADayLeft[LESSON.GetValue()] == 1);

                            while ((passedDoubleCheck || !passedSaturdayCheck || !passedAdditionalCheck || teacherUnavailable || LessonsLeft[LESSON.GetValue()] == 0 || LessonsADayLeft[LESSON.GetValue()] == 0) && implementations > 0)
                            {
                                LESSON.inc(); // Если урок не подходит по какому-то из параметров, то мы меняем урок, который хотим поставить
                                passedSaturdayCheck = (LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].saturday == (day == 5)); // Субботняя проверка, после обновления
                                passedAdditionalCheck = (LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].additional == ((lesson == 6 && shift == 0) || (lesson == 5 && shift == 6)));
                                passedDoubleCheck = (DoubleCheck && LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].aday == 2 && LessonsADayLeft[LESSON.GetValue()] == 0);
                                teacherUnavailable = (tschedules[teachers.IndexOf(LSN[LESSON.GetValue()].teach)].days[day].lessons[lesson].form != ""); // Проверяем, свободен ли учитель после обновления
                                implementations--; // Уменьшаем количество оставшихся попыток
                            }

                            if (implementations == 0) schedules[form].days[day].lessons[lesson] = new Lesson(0, 0, new Subject(" ", 0), new Teacher(" ", " ", " ", null), false, false); // Если попытки закончились, то устаналвиваем пропускной урок
                            else // А если мы нашли подходящий урок, то
                            {
                                schedules[form].days[day].lessons[lesson] = LSN[LESSON.GetValue()]; // Устанавливаем найденный урок
                                LessonsADayLeft[LESSON.GetValue()]--; LessonsLeft[LESSON.GetValue()]--; // Уменьшаем количество оставшихся уроков в день и в неделю
                                LessonsAtAll--; // Уменьшаем количество уроков, которые все ещё нужно куда-то установить
                            }

                        } // Конец цикла перебора уроков
                    } // Конец цикла перебора

                    //MessageBox.Show(LessonsAtAll.ToString());
                    startLessonT.inc(); // Меняем первый урок на случай, если расписание не сгенерировалось и мы снова идем по кругу
                }
                startLesson[form].inc(); // Меняем стартовый урок для класса на случай возвращения сюда
                if (LessonsAtAll != 0) { formFailed = true; } // Если не все уроки установлены в расписании, то нам не удалось его сгенерировать
                if ((backs[0] == LSN.Count() || forms.Count == 1) && formFailed == true) { FAILED = true; break; } // Если первый класс перегенерировался уже максимальное количество раз, то прекращаем пытаться'
                int tempHowBack = 0; // Создаем переменную для возвращения
                if(form > 0) for (tempHowBack = 1; (form - tempHowBack >= 0 && backs[form - tempHowBack] == LSN.Count()); tempHowBack++) ; // Определяем как сильно назад нам нужно вернуться
                if (backSave == form && !formFailed) for (int i = 0; i < backs.Count(); i++) backs[i] = 0; // Если нам удалось сгенерировать то очищаем количество возвращений
                if (form > 0 && formFailed) { backSave = form; form -= (1 + tempHowBack); backs[form+1]++;} // Если не удалось, то возвращаемся на класс назад и создаем ему другое расписание
                if (LessonsAtAll == 0) { formFailed = false; } // Если сгенерировалось, то не провалено лол
                if (!formFailed) // Если провалено
                {
                    for (int day = 0; day < 6; day++) // Перебираем дни для записи в учительское расписание
                    {
                        for (int lesson = 0; lesson < 12; lesson++) // Перебираем уроки для записи в учительское расписание
                        {
                            if (schedules[form].days[day].lessons[lesson].teach.fullname != "     ") // Если урок не пустой, то
                                tschedules[teachers.IndexOf(schedules[form].days[day].lessons[lesson].teach)].days[day].lessons[lesson] = new tLesson(forms[form].fullname, schedules[form].days[day].lessons[lesson].sub.name);
                            // Записали урок в учительское расписание
                        } // Конец перебора уроков для учителей
                    } // Конец перебора дней для учителей
                }
                formFailed = false;
            } // Конец цикла перебора классов

        }

        if (FAILED) this.ShowMessageAsync("Ошибка!", "Не удалось сгенерировать расписание с заданными условиями, попробуйте изменить их.");
        object save = FormsList.SelectedItem;
        FormsList.SelectedItem = null;
        FormsList.SelectedItem = save;
    }<code>`

Comment: А почему заголовок "перебор все вариантов", а не "составление расписания"?

Comment: @Эникейщик А потому что такая задача, если правильно помню, NP-полная, так что придется перебирать все варианты. Только немного дегтя в бочку меда - у меня теща была завучем, и рассказывала, что основные проблемы в расписании бывали в ограничениях типа "Марьванна в четверг с утра сидит с внуком", а "Лидию Евлампиевна устроит скандал, если у нее будет "окно" в уроках", а вот Света работает первый год, ею можно затыкать любые дыры... :( А, с субботой - скорее наоборот, чем в условии - реально была учительница-еврейка, категорически не работавшая в субботу...

Comment: @Harry На скандалы, дыры и внуков можно не обращать внимания, ибо для них есть ручное редактирование :)